# Dynamically add checkboxes, basing on entries in Excel sheet

Tags: javascript, html

Pre-condition: *In an Excel sheet, some names would be present*.

Steps:

1. It would read from the excel sheet.
2. It would create checkboxes in the web page based on the number of entries present in Excel sheet.
3. The name of the checkboxes would be same as present in an Excel sheet.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite easy in jQuery, if you can use it along with HTML webpage, where you will be processing your Excel sheet. jQuery has a perfect iteration functions (.each() is one of them) and can create new objects (including checkboxes) on-the-fly, setting their properties (including name) to anything you want.

I can't provide you with any working example, because you didn't provide enough details on how will the data look, after reading it from Excel sheet.

I assume here that you already have the reading of Excel sheet part done. Because, if not, then believe me -- adding checkboxes to a web page is a piece of cake against problem of reading any Office format on a webpage. This is a whole different problem.